# Microphone not working

Tags: sound, microphone, soundcard

Microphone stopped working. Sound configuration input volume is set to 100% and input level bars graph reach about 50% even with no microphone device connected on the jack. The same happens with both front and rear microphone. When I connect the microphone and try to record, all I can hear is noise. What could I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that somehow your *alsa* configuration has been changed.
Maybe this should provide you some more information what the problem could be:

1. Open the terminal
2. type `alsamixer` and then hit `Enter`

Then the *AlsaMixer* should open and you should see some coloured bars. This mixer more possibilities for adjustments.

1. Check if the bars for *Mic* and *MicBoost* are set to a high level.

Eventually you can try to plug in you microphone and see if you can obtain a clean recording by adjusting the bar levels.

If nothing changes, then I would recommend to try restarting the sound system with

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

If your system uses PulseAudio, then you should also try to kill that process with

```
sudo pulseaudio -k
```

As I read in other posts, sometimes those commands need to be executed various times until they work.